# node-couchdb has port number in _baseurl. How do I remove that?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I am writing a node.js script that will connect me to a server couch database.

However, I am noticing that node-CouchDB automatically places the port number (5984 by default for CouchDB) in the _baseurl.  Is there any way I can remove the port number and get the pulls automatically?

```
console.log('starting file app.js');

const fs = require('fs');

const os = require('os');

const NodeCouchdb = require('node-couchdb');

const request = require('request');


const couch = new NodeCouchdb({
    host: "domain.url.com",
    protocol:"https",
    auth:{
        "user":"admin",
        "password":"admin"
    },
    port: 443
});


console.log("connected");

console.log(couch);
```

> The output for console.log(couch) is:
>
> NodeCouchDB {
>   _baseUrl: 'https://domain.url.com:443',                                                                                                                                                 _cache: null,                                                                                                                                                                                _requestWrappedDefaults:                                                                                                                                                                      { [Function]
>   get: [Function],
>   head: [Function],
>   post: [Function],
>   put: [Function],
>   patch: [Function],
>   del: [Function],
>   delete: [Function],
>   cookie: [Function],
>   jar: [Function],
>   defaults: [Function] } }

I have already mapped the database to port 443 and thus, I am getting a server error when I run this script. help!

Comment: You're code to edit the port is correct. CouchDB defaults to port 5984 and overriding default port is not very straightforward (the best way is what you have already got there). (Reference: https://github.com/request/request/issues/2405). What is the server error you get?

Comment: 400 bad request.  We basically have very strict guidelines on connecting to ports

Comment: Fair enough. Which port is CouchDB listening on?

Comment: We've got a nginx reverse proxy from 443 to 5984.  So it is sufficient if we just connect to the https://dbpath.  While i can just go around this by doing a get request, I thought it would be better to use this lib as I wont have to explain a lot to developers downstream